# Comparison of terms in local formulation of Christoffel-symbols in relation to isometries.

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g),(N,h)$ be semi-riemannian manifolds, and $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(M,N)$ an isometry (hence a diffeomorphism). Let $(U,\psi = (x^1,\ldots,x^n))$ be a coordinate chart of a point $p \in U \subset M$, and $(\varphi(U),\psi \circ \varphi^{-1} = (y^1,\ldots,y^n))$ be a chart of $\varphi(p) \in \varphi(U) \subset N$. By a (I believe) standard-theorem, we get $$T_p\varphi\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p\Big)$$$$ = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \frac{\partial ((\psi \circ \varphi^{-1})^j \circ \varphi \circ \psi^{-1})}{\partial x^i}(\psi(p)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\Big|_{\varphi(p)}$$$$ = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\Big|_{\varphi(p)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}\Big|_{\varphi(p)}.$$

Now, by the definition of isometries, and the calculation above, we get $$g_{ij}(p) := g\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Big|_p\Big) = h\Big(T_p\varphi\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p\Big),T_p\varphi\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Big|_p\Big)\Big) = h\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}\Big|_{\varphi(p)},\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\Big|_{\varphi(p}\Big) = h_{ij}(\varphi(p)).$$

Now, to my question: Why does this imply $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}\Big|_{\varphi(p)} h_{ij} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\Big|_p g_{ij}?$$

I feel like I am missing something obvious. The reason we want to show this is to see that $${}^g\Gamma^k_{ij}(p) = {}^h\Gamma^k_{ij}(\varphi(p))$$ for the Christoffel-symbols on $U,\varphi(U)$ respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will essentially follow from the fact that $y^i = x^i \circ \varphi^{-1}$ (by your definition).

The claim now is to show that for any $f \in C^\infty(M)$, we have that
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\Big|_{p} f = \frac{\partial}{\partial y^k} \Big|_{\varphi(p)} (f \circ \varphi^{-1}) \,,$$
but this is clear since you have already shown that $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^k} \Big|_{\varphi(p)}$ is the pushforward of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\Big|_{p}$.

More explicitly, we can unravel the definition of the pushforward/tangent/differential map to see that:
$$\begin{align} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial y^k} \Big|_{\varphi(p)} (f \circ \varphi^{-1}) 
&= T_p \varphi\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\Big|_{p}\right) (f \circ \varphi^{-1})\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\Big|_{p}(f \circ \varphi^{-1} \circ \varphi)\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\Big|_{p} f
\end{align}$$

Then with $f = g_{ij}$, and using the fact that you showed $h_{ij} = g_{ij} \circ \varphi^{-1}$, your desired result follows.

Comment: I think I see where you are coming from, but I am not sure I follow this step $$T_p\varphi\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\Big|_p\Big)(f \circ \varphi^{-1}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\Big|_p(f \circ \varphi^{-1} \circ \varphi)$$

Comment: That is the definition of the tangent map. For some $F \colon M \to N$, how else are you defining the map $T_p F \colon T_p M \to T_{F(p)} N$?

Comment: I want to accept your answer, but for me to accept it, I need to understand it. I don´t understand how you get from the LHS to the RHS here. I don´t see that it follows from the definition of the tangent-map, but it might be due to my own ignorance.

Comment: No worries, you definitely shouldn't accept the answer until you're satisfied. What book are you using? What is your definition of the tangent map?

For reference, the definition I am using is that with $F \colon M \to N$ smooth, if $v \in T_p M$ then $T_p F (v)$ acts on $ f \in C^\infty(N)$ by $T_p F (v) (f) = v(f \circ F)$

Comment: Oh, my bad, yes, now I understand!

Comment: Actually, there is still something that does not click for me. Is there some way to see this without relying on this definition? We never covered the definition via derivations in my course, explicitly, I believe.

I mean, I see why it follows from the definition, but is there some way to see it without this particular definition?

Comment: What definition are you using? Maybe to elaborate a bit, consider $\varphi: M \to N$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p \in T_p M$ just as you have. We want to "push forward" this vector so that it's also a vector in $T_{\varphi(p)} N$ that acts on $f \in C^\infty(N)$. The only possible way to do this is to pull $f$ back to a function in $C^\infty(M)$, which we do by considering $f \circ \varphi$. In other words, the push forward $T_p\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p\right)$ acts on $f$ by letting $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p$ act on the pulled back $f \circ \varphi$.